# Fedora 33 - gnome-terminal doesn't show up in wmctrl

Tags: fedora, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell, wayland, wmctrl

A while ago I wrote a `wmctrl`-based script I used to implement a hotkey to focus into running *gnome-terminal* instance in order to avoid using mouse when I need to run anything in terminal. After an upgrade to Fedora 33 it seems like `wmctrl -l` doesn't list *gnome-terminal* windows anymore. It does list other windows though - like Chrome browser or Electron apps.

```
mdulko:~/ $ wmctrl -l
0x00a00001  3 fedora The Dandy Warhols - Country Leaver
0x02a0004c  2 fedora release – lower-constraints.txt
0x01c00007  1 fedora Slack | <redacted> | <redacted>
0x01000007  0 fedora Chrome/Chromium 85.0.4183.83 regression workaround : swaywm - Brave
```

This is probably related to usage of Wayland which Fedora defaults to and I use. To script that I'll probably need to call lookingGlass API over gdbus. Is that a good clue?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some more details. First, confirm that you are indeed using Wayland because as far as I know, `wmctrl` is only for Xorg and doesn't work with Wayland. Does `wmctrl -l` show anything at all? If yes, please add it to your question.

Comment: @terdon: I'm using Wayland and `wmctrl -l` does indeed list some of the windows (Chrome and electron apps). I updated the question.

Comment: Please show us the output of `wmctrl -l`, but if it isn't listed, I doubt you can get it to work. You could try using `xdotool`, but I doubt that will work any better with Wayland.

Comment: @terdon: There you go, but as I said, it's only listing Chromium browser and electron apps. I think I'll just switch back to X11 as Wayland has major regression regarding screen sharing too.

Comment: I haven't used Wayland at all, in part precisely because I've read that it doesn't play well with standard tools like `wmctrl`, but you're not the first to mention something like this. If switching back is an option, I would recommend it.

Comment: X tools will only work with legacy X11 apps running under Xwayland, which is the X server provided by Wayland.

Answer (score 1):

**On Ubuntu:**
I got `wmctrl -l` to list `gnome-terminal` windows by disabling Wayland(the default display server) and using Xorg(the older display server) instead.
To disable Wayland, **uncomment** the following line in `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

**I had to restart Ubuntu to see the change.**

More instructions on disabling Wayland are [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/configuring-xorg-as-default-gnome-session/).